# Magento 2 - Test if Static Block is Enabled in custom template

Tags: magento2, static-block

In Magento 1.9, I could test if a CMS Static Block was active with the following code:

```
if ( Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('block_id')->getIsActive() == 1) {...}
```

How would I do the same in Magento 2? This is what I've tried so far:

```
$blockIsActive = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('7')->getIsActive();
if ($blockisActive == 1){..}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use

```
$block->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId(BLOCK_ID)->toHtml();
```

Then there are not need to check block is active or not  because of `Magento\Cms\Block\Block`'s  **`_toHtml()`**  function return content whenever the block is active[ **by checking `if ($block->isActive()) {`**]

---

**Check _toHtml() function of that  class:**

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
       ...
        $html = '';
        if ($blockId) {
             ....
            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
            $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
            ......
            if ($block->isActive()) {
                $html = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent());
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

---

**For logical reference,you can use below**

```
$html=$block->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Cms\Block\Block'
            )->setBlockId(10)->toHtml();

// check it have content
if($html!=''):
 echo $html
endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using below code for any custom template,

```
    $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $blocks = $obj->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Block')->load(7);

    if($blocks->getIsActive()){
       //code
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me as well! Since I was already using ->toHtml I went with other solution for my project.

Comment: Avoid using ObjectManager. Quoting Magento: "Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class." http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html